# Mark pivotitems of the fields with some conditions

Tags: vba, pivotitem

I have few pivotfields and I would like to mark the pivotitems of the fields with some conditions. I have tried using `.visible` and also have used this `application.screenupdating` and `application.displayfilters`. But ist not selecting or deseleting the pivotitems. I would really appreciate each reply.

`Filter_PivotField_by_Date_Range`. This is a function I am calling in my main just to give my field Name and the Dates I want to compare.
After the 2 if conditions I want it to mark (select/Tickmark) the pivotitems in the field and otherwise unmark/ not select the other ones. Make the other one's invisible and then just Exit Sub.

If you guys have any questions I would really help it to make you all clear. Please any comments or code will be appreciated.

```
    Sub Filter_PivotField_by_Date_Range(pvtField As PivotField, it1 As Date, it2 As Date)

        Dim bTemp As Boolean, i As Long
        Dim dtTemp As Date, dtTemp1 As Date


        dtTemp = Format(CDate(it1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        dtTemp1 = Format(CDate(it2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        On Error Resume Next

         With pvtField
          For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count

           dtFrom = .PivotItems(i)
           If (dtTemp <= dtFrom) Then
               If (dtTemp1 >= dtFrom) Then
               On Error Resume Next
                       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                       .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
                       MsgBox (dtFrom)
               Else
                  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                   Exit Sub
               End If

            End If
          Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: If Possible can you please share the screenprint of your Pivot and a sample example of your action and expected output. Sorry for that i am not much clear.

Comment: Hallo SIva, thanku for your reply. It goes like this.... I have a userfrom that takes the starting date and ending date from the user and i made a macro in order to select all the Dates in the Pivot field " planned rel" between the Dates entered by the user. For eg user enters start date as : 11.02.2013 and end date as 01.01.2014. So it should only select 14.08.2013. This is the only date(pivotitem) existing in the Pivot field

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with a small Modification. It worked perfectly for me. Also i had this assumption, your 'it1' is  Start Date and 'it2' is End date.

```
 dtFrom = Format(CDate(.PivotItems(i)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Storing Date range value to array.

```
    it1 = "01/01/2013"
    it2 = "01/01/2014"
    Dim dtTemp1 As Date
    Dim dtTemp2 As Date
    Dim dateArray()
    dtTemp1 = Format(CDate(it1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dtTemp2 = Format(CDate(it2), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    NoOfDays = DateDiff("D", dtTemp1, dtTemp2)
    ReDim dateArray(NoOfDays)

    For i = 0 To NoOfDays
    dateArray(i) = dtTemp1 + i
    Next
```

Comment: Ya it works properly with no such Errors but the Problem is. It's still not marking(selecting) my pivotitems from the field

Comment: Strange: It's really not doing for me. Like all are either marked or unmarked like i leave them before debugging

Comment: Or can you suggest me a way where I can put the Dates entered by the user in some Array. Like for eg from 01.01.2013 to 01.01.2017. so a table or a list contains all the Dates between these Dates and I can use     .application.match(ArrayofDates, ptItem.Name, 0) and then try to make it visible? But I dont know how to make an Array of Dates given by the user

Comment: Did you debug and check if your execution is coming to the '.PivotItems(i).Visible = True'. I also trying for other alternatives

Comment: ya I did it like 100 times. I am having many worksheets and in None of them, its selecting any item

Comment: Hey did you get any method ?

Comment: Nope... Check my code and results. I didnt see the problem of checking or unchecking dates. I see only problem with few dates

Comment: Can u suggest me a way on how to put the Dates entered by the user into an Array. For eg. If a user enters 01.01.2013 and 01.01.2014. So the Array should contain all the Dates from 01.01.2013 till 01.01.2014. @siva

Comment: Sub Sesarray()

                Dim array_dates As Variant
                ReDim array_dates(dtTemp To dtTemp1)
                Dim i1 As Long
   
                      For i1 = LBound(array_dates) To UBound(array_dates)
                                  ''''' I dont know what to write here so that he can take the Vale 1 by 1
                      Next

                  End Sub

Comment: I have given the Code in the answer. I guess this is what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below one and its working fine, if possible share you pivot same date.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Macro7()
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim pvtDATE As Date
    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim x As PivotItem
    Dim it1
    Dim it2
    Dim y
    it1 = "2/2/2016"
    it2 = "2/20/2016"

    Set pvtField = Excel.Sheets("UrSheet").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(2)

    StartDate = Format(CDate(it1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    EndDate = Format(CDate(it2), "dd/mm/yyyy")


            For Each x In pvtField.PivotItems
            If (x.Value <> "(blank)") Then
             pvtDATE = Format(x.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

                If (StartDate <= pvtDATE) Then
                    If (EndDate >= pvtDATE) Then
                        x.Visible = True
                    Else
                        x.Visible = False
                    End If
                Else
                    x.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
            Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. I really appreciate your efforts :) But I am having like 4 worksheets and in 3 of them the field is there. I want that my code should mark the pivotitem of the respective field in each worksheet and with this one it's not doing for a single one.

Comment: Let me Confirm my understanding. You have Pivot tables in 4 sheets and you want to Apply the Filter on all pivots tables in all sheets. Am i right?

Comment: ya exactly this is what I want.

Comment: Its easy we just need to iterate same code for all the sheets. But is the code working fine for you for one sheet now?

Comment: no it is not working fine for even a single sheet and I know what u mean by iterating through each sheet. I have that Thing in my code. What about the code that I just pasted down below. Will it help?

Comment: Im looking into it. Any errors or wht is happening when you run ur code?

Comment: i think instead of '.PivotItems(i)' it should be 'ptItem'

Comment: The new code that I just pasted in which I am vreating an Array to store the Dates. Its giving me an error in this line "Call Sesarray(array_dates())" saying unexpected type

Comment: I guess Array should be declared  as public. You have delcatred it in your 'Test_Filter_Date_Range' and not passed while calling the Filter_PivotField_by_Date_Range also. Also i feel that for creating array do you really need that lenghty code.Please check. Also it1 and it2 are not passed to 'Sesarray' as well. Variable declared in one procedure will not be accessible in other procedures. Please use 'Option Explicit' that will let you know where all the Declarationis required.

Comment: Ya that Problem is resolved by declaring it globally now. But now this line " For i1 = LBound(array_dates) To UBound(array_dates) " in Sub Sesarray is saying subscript out of range. :(

Comment: That is because array size is not available. You have just declared the Dynamic array. You haveto ReDim it. so try finding the no of days between your dates and redim array with the days.

Comment: I cannot declare it. It is according to the Dates entered by the user. My Array should include all the Dates between the Dates entered by the user. So i dont know how many day can come betwwen the dates

Comment: If User Enters "1/15/2016" and "1/25/2016" then calculate the difference of the dates by using 'nodays=DateDiff("D",DATE1,DATE2)' and  then ReDim array_dates(nodays)

Comment: I think you didnt see the edit i did to my first answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: Now again a Problem. Method Range of object failed. :( In this line "Range("dtTemp").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(Range("dtTemp")))" it is showing the error. I wrote this line in order to increase the dtTemp(the 1st date entered by the user). It should be incremented every time so that the Array can have each and every value from 1st date to last date

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2010 or later and these PivotTables share the same PivotCache (i.e. they have the same data source) then you can simply set up a slicer, then connect it to the other PivotTables. Then any changes you make in one will automatically be reflected in the others.(Right click on the Slicer and select Report Connections).

In regards to why your code is failing, can you advise what version of Excel you are using, and what the number format of the PivotField is?  I suspect the code is failing due to a bug in Excel where VBA fails when recognizing Date variables if you have Excel 2007 or 2010 and are using non US regional date settings and the number format of your PivotField is set to General. (The number format will be stuck on General if there are blanks in your source data. You'll need to get rid of those blanks).

I [wrote about this here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/09/a-date-with-pivotitems/)
 and apart from changing the number format of your field, you may also like to [try Micheal's approach](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/09/a-date-with-pivotitems/#comment-638479) from the comments if you have Excel 2010.

I see there's also a possible solution [at this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938973/filtering-between-two-dates-in-pivot-table-using-vba-uk-to-us-date-format-issue?rq=1).

See the following links for more on this:

[Why is this PivotItem.Visible call throwing a TypeMismatch error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424926/cannot-return-many-properties-of-pivotitem)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01cb61c7-5e68-4a45-aeff-a70c6dbfe00f/excel-2007-accessing-pivotitemvisible-gives-error-if-the-field-item-value-is-a-date