# How to detect the visibility of the blank PivotItem

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table on an Excel worksheet. It has a field named "Season", which is a report field with multiple selection and some blank values.
I want to see if the blank values are selected in the filter (i.e., visible) with the following code.

```
Sub ShowVisbilityOfBlankItem()

    Dim PivotField As PivotField
    Set PivotField = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Season")

    Dim PivotItem As PivotItem
    Set PivotItem = PivotField.PivotItems("(blank)")

    Debug.Print PivotItem.Visible ' Runtime Error 13: Type mismatch

End Sub
```

However, the last line results in a Runtime Error 13: Type mismatch. This does not happen for other `PivotItem`s. Is this a bug in Excel (2010) or in my code? Is there another way to determine if blanks are visible?

It is possible to set the visibility of the blank `PivotItem`. Also, the Local Window shows a value `True`for `PivotItem.Visible`, regardless if it is visible or not.

Comment: Your code works for me, and returns the correct value for `.Visible`.  No Error 13.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I am working in a corporate environment where I can't choose the version of Excel.

Comment: Excel 2010 on Win10.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that it is not a code error. I put it down to a glitch in my Excel installation.

Comment: Only going by your name, are you using the German version? I get the same error and I am using the German version. I know that this was a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling some and getting the same error, I came across this reply in a different question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107082/1626443

I think the problem is related to the Excel language version and it can only be processed if the value is literally `(blank)`. I am using the German version and it was `(leer)` before that and it didn't work.

This removed the error for me:

```
sStore = pi.Value
pi.Value = sStore
If pi.Visible Then 'no more error
```

Note, you technically need to do it only once and I think the following code should work as well:

```
If pi.Value = "(BLANK_IN_YOUR_LANGUAGE)" Then pi.Value = "(blank)"
```

And potentially even this one:

```
If pi.Value = "(BLANK_IN_YOUR_LANGUAGE)" Then pi.Value = pi.Value
```

It is an extremely weird and frustrating bug to be honest.

I know this was a year ago but maybe it still helps you or someone else on his journey through `PivotItems`.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem only arises when the language is German and not when the language is English (didn't try other languages). It is also true that setting `PivotItem.Value = PivotItem` (once) made the runtime error go away. However, I can still find the blank `PivotItem`with the value `"(blank)"`, even though the display says `"(leer)"`.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same error using french langage. Unfortunately this is not only related to (blank) value, but to every value that has language interpretation.

I encountered it for values of `PivotItem.value` that come from double type values in my datasource. This is for sure due to decimal separator which is , in french but . in english.

Applying `PivotItem.value=PivotItem.value` makes `.visible` work again, but beware that it changes the value effectively displayed when you open the filter in Excel: `123,456` initially displayed becomes `123.456`.

This may confuse your end user playing with your PivotTable.
This may also change filtering capabilities as it seems new value is considered as a string although it was a double beforehand. So > or < filter will give different results for instance.

This is clearly a bug, but I've found no fix from µsoft so far. I'm using excel2007 and should probably update... with no insurance that it is fixed in recent version