# The if statement is not working while checking pivotItems

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, pivot-table

I am a complete beginner using vba but here's a problem I can not find the answer for.

I am trying to make a toggle for a pivot table filter with vba using the if statement, but my if then statement seems not to be working correctly. Please help and explain what I did wrong here:

```
Sub Set_graph_pack()
'toggle pack filter on/off

    Sheets("Blad4").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel7").PivotFields("afdeling").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel7").PivotFields("afdeling")
   
   If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel7").PivotFields("afdeling").PivotItems("Pack").Visible = True Then
   
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Pack").Visible = False
Else:
        .PivotItems("Pack").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False

End If
End With

    Sheets("dashboard").Select
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

This code does run without any errors, but I don't get the correct answer.

It seems not to check the `pivotitem` but simply when true then continue if false goto then

Comment: If your Excel language setting isn't English, then the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809061/how-to-detect-the-visibility-of-the-blank-pivotitem) might be useful

Comment: sadly this does not seem to fix the issue but thanks for the reply

Comment: Remove the colon `:` from `Else:`.

Comment: sadly this also does not seem to fix the problem thanks for the reply